# Php, google distance matrix always returns false

Tags: php, json, google-maps

here is the link what Im trying with:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=47.02842388681676|18.51792812347412&destinations=47.4735911253571|20.596618652343803&key=*******&language=en&units=metric
```

this works great from browsers. But gives FALSE from php:

```
  $ch = curl_init();
  $url = 'https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins='.urlencode($lat1).'|'.urlencode($long1).'&destinations='.urlencode($lat2).'|'.urlencode($long2).'&key='.urlencode('**********').'&language=en&units=metric';
  echo $url;
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  $c = curl_exec($ch);
  curl_close($ch);
  //$c = json_decode($c);
  echo '<pre>'; var_dump ($c);die;
```

Comment: If RETURNTRANSFER is set to TRUE and you still get FALSE as return then their might be an error. Try curl_error() to get more details.

Comment: "SSL certificate problem: unable to get local issuer certificate"

Comment: Ok, as quick fix you can try "curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try with file_get_contents:

```
$content = file_get_contents('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=47.02842388681676|18.51792812347412&destinations=47.4735911253571|20.596618652343803&key=*******&language=en&units=metric');
$content = json_decode($content);

print_r($content);
```